# Responsive bootstrap 3 buttons side by side without line breaks, only show symbol when too small

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

There are tons of button styling questions out there, but I can not find the one for my case, if you see one please link me to it.

What I want:

- All buttons should be distributed across the whole available width
- As soon as there is an overflow, the text should be hidden and only the symbol shown instead
- Linebreaks should never occur - if space is getting too small even with only symbols left, the overflowing buttons should be hidden

I'm using bootstrap 3.
First my buttons look like this:
[image]
...and when I make my browser window a bit smaller, like this:
[image]

Instead of doing line breaks, I want the buttons to become more narrow.
But since cut-off text would look bad, it should be hidden, only leaving a symbol.
This should also work with 3 buttons, which is currently as mess as well:
[image]

Here's my example, the parent has a certain width, which I simulated by setting it to 75%. The problem is, that the buttons are line breaking now. And I also don't know how to make the text disappear on overflow using only less and css.

```css
.fixed-footer {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed-footer">
  <div class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Neues Projekt</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href=""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Projekte exportieren</a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Bearbeiten</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _“And I also don't know how to make the text disappear on overflow using only css”_ - I doubt that is possible at all … (at least if you want it to be flexible & dynamic, and not do a lot of measuring upfront to arrive at some “magic numbers”.)

Comment: There is no magic css to do this automatically - you will need to calculate your overflow breakpoints and add in media queries to handle it (wrap the text in a span and use display none when you hit the breakpoints)

Comment: thx for the info, I added that I'm using less, maybe it's possible then?

Comment: @Cold_Class it is possible. Using media query breakpoints. Im not sure about bootstrap 3 but in bootstrap 4 you can have `flex` display and there a ton of options for alignment and distribution. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

Make the button parent flex-container.

Then give `flex:1` to each button, this will make them flexible and also u will be able to add more buttons.

Then using the `@media(max-width:400px)` rule, hide the text below 400px

Add this to your css

```
.b-container {
  display: flex;
}

.b-container .btn {
  flex: 1
}

@media(max-width:400px) {
  .b-container .text {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```css
.fixed-footer {
  width: 75%;
}

.b-container {
  display: flex;
}

.b-container .btn {
  flex: 1
}

@media(max-width:400px) {
  .b-container .text {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed-footer">
  <div class="btn-toolbar b-container">

    <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <span class="text"> Neues Projekt  </span>
    </button>


    <a class="btn btn-success" href=""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> <span class="text">Projekte exportieren </span>
    </a>


    <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i><span class="text"> Bearbeiten</span>
    </button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that trick with flex:1 - and I guess there's no easy way to generalize it by automatically checking for overflow, so using @media seems to be the best workaround

Answer (score 1):

You can add `span` tag around button text.
Here I have added span with class `btn__txt`

then hide it in small screen using media queries

```css
.fixed-footer {
  width: 75%;
}
 
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .btn .btn__txt{
    display:none;
  }  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed-footer">
  <div class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span class="btn__txt"> Neues Projekt</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href=""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i><span class="btn__txt"> Projekte exportieren</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span class="btn__txt">Bearbeiten</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```